# Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888) Can't create callback thread. Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pigpio

Have connected DHT11 to Rpi4.

VCC--pin 1

datapin--gpio4

Ground pin--pin 6

It works fine fine but after giving the result for few times then I get this error.
New to pigpio please do help me figure out what's wrong

```
import time
from pigpio_dht import DHT11, DHT22
while True:
        gpio = 4 # BCM Numbering

        sensor = DHT11(gpio)
#sensor = DHT22(gpio)

        result = sensor.read()

        temperature=([value for value in result.values()][0])
        print(temperature)

        humidity=([value for value in result.values()][2])
        print(humidity)
        time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
28
46

28
46

28
46

28
46

28
46
```

and then I get the following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Can't create callback thread.
Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dht8.py", line 9, in <module>
    sensor = DHT11(gpio)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pigpio_dht/dht11.py", line 24, in __init__
    super(DHT11, self).__init__(gpio, pi=pi, timeout_secs=timeout_secs, use_internal_pullup=True, max_read_rate_secs=1, datum_byte_count=1)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pigpio_dht/dhtxx.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._pi.set_pull_up_down(gpio, pigpio.PUD_UP)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1385, in set_pull_up_down
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_PUD, gpio, pud))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 993, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must do the setup stuff outside of while loop as it creates a new instance of connection. Move your `gpio = 4 # BCM Numbering` and `sensor = DHT11(gpio)` outside of while loop

Comment: @BijayRegmi yea..your right..its working now..thank you

Comment: created an answer for anyone looking for this in future

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up device inside the `while` loop, so it creates multiple instances of same device, hence the error code

```
Can't create callback thread.
Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections.
```

You need to create one device instance and read the info from sensor chronically. Something like this would work:

```
import time
from pigpio_dht import DHT11, DHT22

gpio = 4 # BCM Numbering

sensor = DHT11(gpio)
   
while True:
       
        result = sensor.read()

        temperature=([value for value in result.values()][0])
        print(temperature)

        humidity=([value for value in result.values()][2])
        print(humidity)
        time.sleep(10)
```